# "Moments" cannot be resolved to a type in opencv

Tags: android, opencv, tesseract

I have tried text extractor project using opencv with tesseract library.
while importing that project i also added tesseract as library.
But it Showing error in following of my code.

```
Moments moments = Imgproc.moments(largest.get(0));
        Point center = new Point(0,0);
        center.x = moments.get_m10() / moments.get_m00();
        center.y = moments.get_m01() / moments.get_m00();

        List<Point> points = largest.get(0).toList();
        points = sortCorners(points, center);
```

Error is

> Moments cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: is there anything like namespaces in java/android? maybe it is sth. like cv2.Moments instead

Comment: I am not catching what you are telling @ Micka

Comment: in C++, openCV types and functions start with a `cv::` , for example `cv::Point` but to avoid writing `cv::` all the time, over and over, you can use `using namespace cv`. MAYBE that's similar in Java/Android.

Comment: But i m not using c++. im using java

Comment: "MAYBE that's similar in Java/Android." - I don't know, it was just a hint.

Comment: System.loadLibrary("pngt"); here showing error

Comment: Have a look : http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/imgproc/Moments.html

Comment: ZdaR In you sent link contains only what are the methods available in the moments class. But for me in moment class only importing problem is there. Previous i used opencv 2.4 library now i m using 3.0 after changing only this problem came